# How to extend a WPF window for a certain condition?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, combobox

I have a WPF window that only has a ComboBox (drop down list). If I choose index 1 (second item on the drop down list), how can I extend that WPF window to show more buttons, textbox, etc? Would I need to use the selectedIndex property? If so how do I make the window extend in the XAML.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a `IValueConverter` in the past to accomplish this.  Here is a sample converter:

```
public class MyConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter {

    public object Convert ( object value , Type targetType , object parameter , CultureInfo culture ) {

        if ( value == null )
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

        if ( parameter == null )
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

        if ( value.ToString().Equals ( parameter ) )
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        return System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack ( object value , Type targetType , object parameter , CultureInfo culture ) {
        throw new NotImplementedException ( );
    }
}
```

What this does is, it takes the value that is passed to it, I am expecting a number such as the SelectedIndex of an items control.  I then compare it to the parameter that is passed.  If they are equal, I return Visibility.Visible.  In all other instances, I return Visibility.Hidden.

Now, you can take that and plug it into the XAML like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="vConv"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <ComboBoxItem>Hidden</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Visible</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>

        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="219,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=comboBox, Path=SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource vConv}, ConverterParameter=1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can see that we created an instance of our MyConverter class in the Window.Resources.  When we use this in our binding, we can show/hide my label based on whatever index is selected.  Now this is very basic and you can add a lot to this to get all the functionality you need, bu this should get you started.

Comment: Instead of the huge white blank space in the left, is there a way to actually resize the window to expand? For example if the window was originally 100 by 100 and a combo item was clicked, can I change the window to 100 by 300?

Comment: @tralifa You need to read about Storyboard and Animations in WPF for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth` property of the window on selection of the comboBox Item. Like this:

*On Selection Change event of combobox.Use this*

```
MainWindow obj= new MainWindow();
if(mycombobox.SelectedIndex==0)
    {
       obj.MaxWidth="600";
       obj.MinWidth="600";
    }
if(mycombobox.SelectedIndex==1)
    {
      obj.MaxWidth="200";
      obj.MinWidth="200";
    }
```

or you also can do this

```
 if(mycombobox.SelectedIndex==0)
        {
           this.MaxWidth="600";
           this.MinWidth="600";
        }
    if(mycombobox.SelectedIndex==1)
        {
          this.MaxWidth="200";
          this.MinWidth="200";
        }
```